# Achievement System - Relation check if conditions met, sum points

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am creating an achievement system and I am currently stuck on such case.

Does the user complete all the achievements?

For simplicity and understanding, let's assume *Achievements* class is a Quests class. Multiple Quests are inside the *Achievements_Group* class.

My query to get Players achievements, it isn't perfect. I was considering some PHP looping over the result to calculate **if a player has completed all the quests in Achievements_Group** I am not sure if this is possible to do over the query. Below I will present you the most important schema parts of the database.

```
Achievements_Player::
                with(['achievements' , 'achievements.group'])
                    ->ForPlayer(2)
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray();
```

Schema :: class Achievements

```
+---------+--------+--------+-------+
|  id     | name   | points | Group |
+---------+--------+--------+-------+
|       1 |Quest 1 |     10 |     1 |
|       2 |Quest 2 |     10 |     1 |
|       3 |Quest 3 |     10 |     1 |
|       4 |Quest 4 |     10 |     1 |
|       5 |Quest 5 |     10 |     2 |
+---------+--------+--------+-------+
```

```
class Achievements extends Model
{
    protected $table = "achievements";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['identifier', 'name', 'points', 'description', 'notes', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'category'];
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Achievements_Group::class, 'id', 'group');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Achievements_Category::class, 'id', 'category');
    }
```

Achievements_Group is like a wrapper for all Achievements - which you can consider beeing quests.

Schema for class Achievements_Group

```
+----+-------------------+--------+--------+
| id |       name        | points | reward |
+----+-------------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Achievements Gr.1 |     30 |      1 |
|  2 | Achievements Gr.2 |     50 |      2 |
+----+-------------------+--------+--------+
```

```
class Achievements_Group extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'achievements_group';
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['name',
        'description',
        'questCount',
        'points',
        'notes',
        'type',
        'identifier'];


    public function quests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Achievements::class, 'group', 'id');
    }

    public function reward()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Achievements_Reward::class, 'id', 'reward');
    }
}
```

Achievements_Player table is simple. It consists of fields player_id and achievement_id ( class Achievements table achievements )

```
+-----+-----------+-----------------+
| id  | player_id |  achievement_id |
+-----+-----------+-----------------+
|   1 |         1 |               1 |
|   2 |         1 |               2 |
|   3 |         1 |               3 |
|   4 |         1 |               4 |
|   5 |         2 |               5 |
+-----+-----------+-----------------+
```

```
class Achievements_Player extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'achievements_player';
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['achievement_id', 'player_id'];

    public function achievements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Achievements::class, 'id', 'achievement_id');
    }
    public function scopeForPlayer($query, $player_id)
    {
        return $query->where('player_id', $player_id);
    }
}
```

Rewards schema class Achievements_Reward

```
+----+-------------+
| id |    value    |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Some reward |
|  2 | Some reward |
+----+-------------+
```

```
class Achievements_Reward extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'achievements_reward';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['*'];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Achievements_Group::class, 'reward', 'id');
    }


}
```

Is it possible to determine if a player has completed the Achievements_Group table and display the result? Example lets assume we want to calculate the points for player 1. We can see that he should have 40 points form the Achievements class ( table ), but he also fulfilled them all so he should be granted the group 1, points + 30.

Any directions on how to solve this, either tell me if this should be done by  PHP or a better query would be appreciated.

> Update 1.

Added this relation to Achievements class

```
 public function completed()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Achievements_Player::class, 'achievement_id', 'id');
    }
```

And I am finding players quests with the group as such

```
Achievements_Group::
                with(['quests', 'quests.completed' => function ($q) {
                    $q->where('player_id',2);
                }])
                    ->get()
                    ->toArray()
```

The following query is generating my expected result - since I could now actually count the points in PHP and check if all quests have been done in one group.

```
0 => array:11 [
    "id" => 1
    "name" => " Achievements Gr.1"
    "reward" => 1
    "points" => 30
    "quests" => array:8 [
     0 => array:11 [
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Quest 1"
        "points" => 10
        "group" => 1
        "completed" => []
      ],
      1 => array:11 [
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "Quest 2"
        "points" => 10
        "group" => 1
        "completed" => [
            0 => array:5 [
                "id" => 20
                "player_id" => 2
                "achievement_id" => 2
            ]
        ]
      ],
      2 => array:11 [
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "Quest 3"
        "points" => 10
        "group" => 1
        "completed" => []
      ],
      3 => array:11 [
        "id" => 4
        "name" => "Quest 4"
        "points" => 10
        "group" => 1
        "completed" => []
      ]
    ]
],
1 => array:11 [
    "id" => 2
    "name" => " Achievements Gr.2"
    "reward" => 1
    "points" => 50
    "quests" => array:8 [
     0 => array:11 [
        "id" => 5
        "name" => "Quest 5"
        "points" => 10
        "group" => 1
        "completed" => []
      ],
    ]
]
```

Two questions, is this an optimal way ( considering I want to load players achievements including the not completed one ) - I assume yes.

I am also a bit concerned about the generated query

```
"query" => "select * from `achievements_player` where `achievements_player`.`achievement_id` in (10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 52, 53, 54, 56) and `player_id` = ?"
```

Should I be concerned ? when there will be more records the in array might get big..

If you can positively answer my 2 questions above consider this question answered.

Comment: is there any particular reason you're not using many to many in achievement players ? you can use many to many, therefore you can use hasManyThrough to achievement_group to calculate total points

Comment: @GhiffariAssamar I added an Update 1. section. I tried hasManyThrough in the player as  hasManyThrough(Achievements_Group,Achievements) but the result wasn't as neat or complete as my query..